Why does my counter keep decrementing even after I don't press the switch then increments afterwards? How do I fix it?
I am using arduino to make a counter that increments if I don't press a switch connected to my arduino then decrements as long as I am pressing the switch. The counter is a 7 segment anode display. In my set up, the counter decrements just fine if I press the switch but once I let go, it keeps decrementing for a while until it starts to increment again. What's going on?
Arduino code:
https://pastebin.com/qvEcqnCt

You need to post the relevant parts of the code here, on this site, using code formatting.

The main issue is that your code lacks button debouncing, so when pressing/letting go of it, any random value might be kept for the duration of the whole delay. "Busy-wait" delays are generally considered bad practice in microcontroller programming, since they stall the CPU for no good reason.
Both of these problems could be solved by using hardware peripheral timers (or the poor man's alternative in Arduino, some millis spaghetti code). Set up a cyclic timer, optionally with interrupt, which scans the buttons every 5ms or 10ms, then compares the port with the previous value read. Only accept changes when the port has been stable since the last time.
Similarly, another timer could be used to update the 7 segment display on regular basis.
On the hardware side of things, the button must have a pull resistor towards the MCU pin. Either an external one or a built-in one enabled in the GPIO peripheral of the MCU. You could also do debouncing in hardware instead of software, by combining a capacitor and a resistor (RC low pass filter).

Any idea how to debounce if we're pressing the switch for a long time? I know how to do it for single presses but I can't visualize how it will go down for long presses.

@Avery Add a separate counter variable which you zero when the button is pressed down. If you debounce every 10ms and increase the counter each time a valid read is confirmed, you can also tell how long the button has been pressed, with some +/-10ms accuracy.


once I let go, it keeps decrementing for a while until it starts to increment again

Without the schematic it is likely that the only a switch is connected, without a pull-up or pull-down resistor.
